# Call a method of unknown class

Tags: java, javafx

I have few controllers and every one has init() method. The question is, how can I call the method for each of loaded stages/controllers? The code below works ok but I don't want to write scenario for every possible controller class.

Briefly, I want this:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("somefxmlfile.fxml"));
if (loader.getController() instanceof LoginController) {
    ((LoginController) loader.getController()).init();
}
```

to be replaced by something like this:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("somefxmlfile.fxml"));
if (loader.getController() instanceof Class<T extends Controller>) {
     ((Class<T extends Controller>) loader.getController()).init();
}
```

I am messing around it for a while and can't write a proper code.

Comment: Silly question, easy answer. Thanks.

Comment: I really like the second part of your answer. Nice one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ideas that come to my mind:

- If one has control over the class `Controller`, then one could give it a `public abstract void init()` - method and implement it in all classes extending `Controller`
- Alternatively, one could do it the Spring-way by annotating a method with some custom annotation (e.g. `@PostConstruct` or `@InitMethod`) and scan for a method in the controller annotated with this annotation and execute it after construction.

Comment: Have one more question. Let's say I have one inheriting class more (scenario: Controller << LoginController << ExtendedLoginController). Calling Controller class abstract method init() like in the question works for LoginController but for ExtendedLoginController doesn't. What's the trick to make it happen?

Comment: Please read [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post). --- There is no inherent reason it should not work. But for a detailed analysis, I would need more information.